# how to add border color to one side of a material button?

Tags: android

This question is not for android Button. kindly answer for Material button.
i wanted a button like below 
[image]

So i used material Button and my code was like this

```
    <style name="CustomShapeAppearance_left">
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">16dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomShapeAppearance_right">
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Previous"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance_left" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Next"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance_right" />
```

I'm getting the result except the Seperation line between the two button.
So, im trying to add border color at right and left side of ech button so ill get the result.
but how to do it for material button.

Comment: why don't you leave a tiny space between the two buttons instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a view between those two button like -

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Previous"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance_left" />

<View 
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Next"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance_right" />
```